# ¿Cómo llamar a un objeto desde un evento onclick javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Realizo una pequeña practica e intento llamar a un objeto desde `onclick` en un botón, puedo llamar a la función directamente pero quería hacerlo llamando al objeto para practicar, pero me da error. He revisado mi sintaxis y no encuentro error (al parecer) entonces quisiera saber si tengo algo mal o esto no es posible? Este es mi código.

Código en `html` del `input`

```
<button onclick = "Usuario.total();"class = "Aceptar" id = "aceptar">Listo</button>
```

```
var Usuario = new Auto();
```

```
class Auto {


function total(){
    alert('hola');
}

}
```

El error que me aparece es:

> SyntaxError: fields are not currently supported

y que `Auto` no está definido.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplemente por que estas creando la instancia de la clase Auto en el objeto Usuario, antes de que dicha clase sea creada; es decir cuando lee:

```
var Usuario = new Auto()
```

Esa clase `Auto` aún no existe y por eso lo marca como no **No definido**, entonces mueve su declaración al final de donde termina el cuerpo de la clase

Segundo quita del método la palabra reservada `function` y déjalo así:

```
total(){
    alert('hola')
}
```

*hasta donde conozco los métodos dentro de las clases no lo requieren* **y usarlo pudiera generar un error de este tipo**

> "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Por último tu código debería lucir de este modo:

```
class Auto {


total(){
    alert('hola')
}

}
var Usuario = new Auto();
```

Comment: Es verdad. Ya funciona, error de novato, muchas gracias!